# ZeroClipboard's buttons are not clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, zeroclipboard

I'm trying to get the demo of ZeroClipboard from their github page working but I'm experiencing several issues.
I've looked into several possibilities but I simply cannot find the issue.

Here is the code copied directly from their github page:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      .clip_button {
        text-align: center;
        border: 1px solid black;
        background-color: #ccc;
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
      }
      .clip_button.zeroclipboard-is-hover { background-color: #eee; }
      .clip_button.zeroclipboard-is-active { background-color: #aaa; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ZeroClipboard.js"></script>

    <div class="clip_button">Copy To Clipboard</div>
    <div class="clip_button">Copy This Too!</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var client = new ZeroClipboard( $('.clip_button') );

      client.on( 'ready', function(event) {
        // console.log( 'movie is loaded' );

        client.on( 'copy', function(event) {
          event.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', event.target.innerHTML);
        } );

        client.on( 'aftercopy', function(event) {
          console.log('Copied text to clipboard: ' + event.data['text/plain']);
        } );
      } );

      client.on( 'error', function(event) {
        // console.log( 'ZeroClipboard error of type "' + event.name + '": ' + event.message );
        ZeroClipboard.destroy();
      } );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is a screenshot of my directory:

http://puu.sh/bv6oA/959b37eefc.png

When I load the page, the divs are there but they are not buttons and they are not clickable.
As a result, no text is copied to clipboard.

Any ideas?
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

ZeroClipboard only accepts plain DOM elements, not jQuery.

Try getting the element like this.

```
      var client = new ZeroClipboard( $('.clip_button')[0] );
```

You can also check out [zClip](http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/), a jQuery ZeroClipboard plugin.